# ¿Como puedo extraer archivo zip en laravel?, mi código me manda error

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, zip

Tengo un problema con descomprimir un archivo zip en laravel de un servidor de ubuntu 20.04. Obtengo un archivo zip a partir de un formulario que solo tiene el campo para subir el archivo y lo quiero procesar como se muestra en el siguiente código, pero me manda este error:

> ZipArchive::extractTo(/var/www/html/shop/public/carim/css.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied.

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

```
public function subirImagenesProccess(Request $request){

    if ($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"]) 
    {
        $nombre = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];    //obtenemos datos de nuestro ZIP
        $ruta = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
        $tipo = $_FILES["zip_file"]["type"];

        echo ($nombre."+   ".$ruta."+   ".$tipo."<br>");

        $zip = new ZipArchive;
            
        if ($zip->open($ruta) === TRUE) //en la función open se le pasa la ruta de nuestro archivo (alojada en carpeta temporal)
        {
            $zip->extractTo('/var/www/html/shop/public/carim');//Aquí me manda ERROR
            $zip->close();
            echo "All well";
        }else{
            echo "Error en la ruta <br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Que pasa si lo extraes en el directorio storage/app? Por ejemplo `$zip->extractTo(storage_path('app/public'));`

Comment: Eso es mas permisos de escritura, debes de dar permisos de escritura solo a la carpeta public desde el servidor

Comment: La carpeta que señalo al final en mi ruta ya tiene permisos. No basta con esa carpeta o forzosamente también la carpeta public?

Comment: Le acabo de dar permisos a la carpeta public y ya corrió a la perfección. Muchas gracias!!!